# Durandal MVC app running under IIS virtual directory

Tags: durandal

I'm struggling with setting up Durandal to run under an IIS virtual folder, when using `PushState :true` in the router config.

Works fine when running through say `http://localhost:24567`

But if I run under `http://localhost/testapp` (testapp is the virtual folder), the routes don't work, and the route links are being rendered without the virtual folder "testapp"

Is there a way to set a base url either using require.js config or via Durandal router?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, feeling a little stupid and should have RTFM!

There is a **root** option when activating the router, especially for when using push-state.

http://durandaljs.com/documentation/Using-The-Router.html

```
        router.map([
            { route: '', title:'Welcome', moduleId: 'viewmodels/welcome', nav: true },
            { route: 'flickr', moduleId: 'viewmodels/flickr', nav: true }
        ]).buildNavigationModel();

        return router.activate({ pushState : true ,root:'/MvcApplication1'});
```

Moral of the story, read the manual more carefully.

Thanks to Yago who has authored a fantastic demo app for Durandal that includes membership/client side authorisation as well as oauth logins,
[Durandal Auth](https://durandalauth.azurewebsites.net/)

Comment: I have similar behaviour except that I'm not using push state. I simply tried to deploy the web generated by the project template, without making a single change. As you describe it works when served by the test webserver. For me the splash screen is shown but there it stays, when served by IIS.

Comment: Peter - maybe try this (might not matter about push-state) return router.activate({root:'/MvcApplication1'});

Comment: I`m using the same sample code (DurandalAuth) and have the same problem mentioned above - loading screen remains opened. By opening Developer Tools I can see that the problem is that the path towards the require.js file is wrong after the sample is deployed on the local IIS webserver. It uses http://localhost/Scripts/require.js  instead of http://localhost/durandal/Scripts/require.js. Even when setting the root to root:'/durandal' it still doesn't work. Any ideas on what can be done?